# 2D Arrays with several for loops

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I am fairly new at Java and have been having some issues understanding a code within my course and it is slowing me up. Can someone kindly give me a step by step of what the 1st for loop is doing? I get confused at what value is `arr[row]` getting?

When I look at the result it makes sense that it is `1 2 3 4 5 6` BUT is the 1st for loop generating and then going to the second one? if so, what is the second one doing since we are starting at `row=0`? and `col=0`? I really need help to move forward with this. Here is the code:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] arr = new int[6][];

    for(int row = 0; row < arr.length; row++)
      arr[row]= new int[row + 1];

    for(int row = 0; row < arr.length; row++){
      for(int col = 0; col < arr[row].length; col++){
        arr[row][col] = (row + 1) *(col +1);
        //System.out.print(arr[row][col] + " ");
        System.out.print("row[" + row + "]"+ "col["+col +"]= "+arr[row][col] + " ");
      }
      System.out.println(); //new line
    }
  }
```

Comment: `arr[row]` in the first loop is just creating "columns" for that `row`.  The second one just adds values to the rows and columns that you've created.

Comment: The first for loop (above the nested one ) initializes each row with a certain length equal to `row + 1`. In the nested loop in the second for loop(s), it assigns a value to each cell and then prints it.

Comment: you can debug the program to see what values each and every variable getting while execution happening and to see how execution flow happening

Comment: The comments saying "you can debug it, so we won't explain everything" might seem a bit harsh, but it is actually a quite crucial skill to be able to understand unknown code. There will not always be someone to explain the code to you.
In this case it should be quite simple. As long as you know what a 2D-Array is, you shouldn't have any problem understanding what is going on there.

Comment: Thank you  Anoop R Desai and SomeDude...It was the only clarification I needed to understand the whole thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is just creating a multidimensional array, each row with one more slot then the previous.
Something like this:

```
[]
[][]
[][][]
[][][][]
[][][][][]
[][][][][][]
```

The second (couple of) `for` scans every element and assign a value proportionated to its dimensions. So it'll be:

```
[1]
[2][4]
[3][6][9]
[4][8][12][16]
[5][10][15][20][25]
[6][12][18][24][30][36]
```

It really reminds me of [Fibonacci sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number)

Hope I helped

Comment: YES! You've helped. Thanks a millions